# Calculate the amount of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

How to calculate the amount of non-trivial ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/ 60 \mathbb{Z}$?

When we are talking about fields it's always 2, but I have no idea from which side I should start tackle this problem. 
I think it somehow related to  number of divisors of 60.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, and you're looking for the number of ideals containing the ideal $60\mathbb{Z}$. You're on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideals are in particular additive subgroups. The additive subgroups of a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ are all cyclic and they are in bijection with the divisors of $n$.

In this case they are the subgroups $\{\overline{kd} | k\in \mathbb Z\}$, where $d$ is a fixed divisor of $60$. It is easy to see they also absorb multiplication, so they are ideals.

Comment: So in this case the ideals and additive subgroups coincide.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of ideal in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$?

Comment: For example, the ideals in $\mathbb Z/ 10\mathbb Z$ are $\{0\}.\{0,5\}.\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ and $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$